# PostgreSQL server user-admin roles to approve changes to db from a lower-role admin

Tags: postgresql, firebird, roles, server-administration

Server administrative roles for PostgreSQL need to be configured in a way that there are high-level/role admins that will approve/allow all of the changes made to a database by lower-level/role admins.

I know there are roles for admins but the question is how to create that approval mechanism?

Also, can that be done better with Firebird database?

Comment: Are you talking only about schema changes (DDL), or also about data changes (DML)?

Comment: @jjanes both of them, that is any changes.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in a single question.

Answer (score 1):

There are no facilities in PostgreSQL for something like this.

You can of course write triggers that record the attempted changes in a second “approval table” instead, plus a function that applies changes from that approval table.

Comment: thank you. But if a lower-level admin makes a column or changes a value, that change will immediately be applied so there is nothing to approve with the exception that we can record that cahnge is a separate table and change it back if needed. 
So, I don't really understand "function that applies changes from that approval table." ... is there a way to "freeze" the changes made by a lower-level admin until approved?

Comment: @CodeGust The trigger could record the change attempt, but block the change from actually occurring.

Comment: ok, so if I create a trigger on any action for  user of a specific role, that trigger can block the action and record it into a table - correct?

Comment: Yes - it inserts into a table and then returns NULL to abort the original operation.